# asp-action inside form doesn't go to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form :

```
@model TodoItem
<form asp-action="/Todo/AddItem" method="POST">
    <label asp-for="Title">Add a new item:</label>
    <input asp-for="Title">
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

I call it in the Index.html

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("AddItemPartial", new TodoItem())
```

that calls the controller on button click :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddItem(TodoItem newItem)
{ 
  //code that calls service...
}
```

I never hit a breakpoint on AddItem, I read that it might be from the asp-action not firing due to _ViewImports.cshtml not being in the same folder or that it didn't cointain @addTagHelper. Tried those solutions, but didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think when you use asp-action, you should only specify action name and not the complete path.

For ex. If below is the code in your page:

```
<form asp-controller="Demo" asp-action="Register" method="post">
    <!-- Input and Submit elements -->
</form>
```

This code is converted to below code:

```
<form method="post" action="/Demo/Register">
    <!-- Input and Submit elements -->
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="<removed for brevity>" />
</form>
```

Please check that after the server side code converted to HTML, there is no asp-action, there is only action attribute understood by HTML form.

For you, you will have to change code to :

```
@model TodoItem
<form asp-controller="Todo" asp-action="AddItem" method="POST">
    <label asp-for="Title">Add a new item:</label>
    <input asp-for="Title">
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, when I put Todo in asp-controller it returns a 404, if I put the full name TodoController it's the same as before

Comment: It turns out that it works for other controllers, just not this one, so the problem is elsewhere, this helped me, thank you

Comment: It is from the parameters in the controller, I made a separate question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54850208/cannot-route-to-controller-with-parameters

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: If you could take a look at the more detailed question that would be great, thank you

Answer (score 0):

When [@Andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10651499/andrea) mentioned that adding the file **_ViewImports** might resolve the issue, I tried it on my project where the data wasn't being forwarded to the controller and it worked.